# Google Cloud IoT - Single MQTT client instance for all devices in a registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot, paho

I am able to publish events to a device in my Cloud IOT Registry via an MQTT client created this way (using paho python):

```
self.__client = mqtt.Client(client_id='projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}/devices/{}'.format(project_id,
                                                                                                 cloud_region,
                                                                                                 registry_id,
                                                                                                 device_id))
```

Now I'm wondering if I can create an MQTT client being able to publish events to multiple devices by setting the client id at registry level (i.e. not specifying the device id):

```
        self.__client = mqtt.Client(client_id='projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}'.format(project_id,
                                                                                                     cloud_region,
                                                                                                     registry_id))
```

This client is not able to connect even if I've added a CA Certificate to the registry.

My question is: can a single MQTT Client instance publish events to a set of devices defined in a registry?
Should I use a gateway instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't send messages to a registry like this.

The way you'd want to do this is either 1) Use a gateway like you say, send one message then spread it to the devices locally. Or 2) Grab the list of devices in the registry using the `DeviceManagerClient()`, and iterate over them each sending each device the message in a loop.

Check out this: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/device-manager-samples#list_devices_in_a_registry

For fetching the list of devices in a registry. Snippet for python:

```
# project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
# cloud_region = 'us-central1'
# registry_id = 'your-registry-id'
print("Listing devices")

client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()
registry_path = client.registry_path(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id)

devices = list(client.list_devices(request={"parent": registry_path}))
for device in devices:
    print("Device: {} : {}".format(device.num_id, device.id))

return devices
```

So in that `for device in devices` loop you can call your code to get the MQTT client and send the message you want to the specified device.